# How to export revision history from PVCS?

Tags: repository, system, pvcs, serena

I have inherited an old server that has a PVCS Version Manager installed. I have tried the "get" but it only exports the latest changes. Is there a way to export revision history from Serena?

Answer (score 1):

In the view menu select "Show Revisions".  This will display a panel below your file list.  Right click the revision you want and select "Get".  You can then specify the location where you want to save the file.